# INNER JOIN only selecting the first row MYSQL during summation

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

Experiments

| id | authId | numUpVotes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 5 |
| 2 | efgh | 3 |
| 3 | efgh | 10 |

Comments

| id | authId | numUpVotes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 2 |
| 2 | abcd | 2 |
| 3 | efgh | 1 |

My goal is SUM all the upvotes for a given authID across both tables, and for that I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(upVotes) as totalUpVotes, authId FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(c.numUpVotes) as upVotes, authId
    FROM Comments c
    WHERE c.authId = 'abcd'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(e.numUpVotes) as upVotes, authId
    FROM Experiments e
    WHERE e.authId = 'abcd') as upVotes;
```

which works and returns

| authId | TotalUpVotes |
| --- | --- |
| abcd | 9 |

But I want to get this for all authId's, not just 'abcd'. So for that I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.authId, SUM(t2.upVotes) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT authId FROM Experiments) as t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT SUM(c.numUpVotes) as upVotes, authId
    FROM Comments c
    GROUP BY authId
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(e.numUpVotes) as upVotes, authId
    FROM Experiments e
    GROUP BY authId
) as t2
ON t1.authId = t2.authId;
```

But it only returns the first authId with all upVotes:

```
| authId| TotalUpVotes|
| -------------- | ---|
| abcd          |  23
```

I want this:

| authId | TotalUpVotes |
| --- | --- |
| abcd | 9 |
| efgh | 14 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` without `WHERE` in the derived table and don't join.

```
SELECT authid,
       sum(numupvotes) totalupvotes
       FROM (SELECT authid,
                    numupvotes
                    FROM experiments
             UNION ALL
             SELECT authid,
                    numupvotes
                    FROM comments) x
       GROUP BY authid;
```

You may also experiment if preaggregating helps with performance (Check the plans.).

```
SELECT authid,
       sum(numupvotes) totalupvotes
       FROM (SELECT authid,
                    sum(numupvotes) numupvotes
                    FROM experiments
                    GROUP BY authid
             UNION ALL
             SELECT authid,
                    sum(numupvotes) numupvotes
                    FROM comments
                    GROUP BY authid) x
       GROUP BY authid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UION all, as bioth tables have the same design you can simpoy use

SELECT *

ESELSe you need the same number of columns

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Experiments (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `authId` VARCHAR(4),
>   `numUpVotes` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Experiments
>   (`id`, `authId`, `numUpVotes`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'abcd', '5'),
>   ('2', 'efgh', '3'),
>   ('3', 'efgh', '10');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Comments (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `authId` VARCHAR(4),
>   `numUpVotes` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Comments
>   (`id`, `authId`, `numUpVotes`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'abcd', '2'),
>   ('2', 'abcd', '2'),
>   ('3', 'efgh', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `authId`, SUM(`numUpVotes`)
> FROM 
> (SELECT * FROM Comments UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Experiments) t1
> GROUP BY `authId`
> ```
>
> ```
> authId | SUM(`numUpVotes`)
> :----- | ----------------:
> abcd   |                 9
> efgh   |                14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b00de3faf1446cf75e1eeb39bd0e6b08)*